# Accessing Files in the Raw folder in Android

Tags: android, audio, export, wav

I am working on an exporting function in an Android application. The files are wav files which are stored in the res/raw folder. How can I access the files?

```
uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + selection[i]);


            try{
                file[i] = new File(uri.getPath());
                if(file[i].exists()){
                    Log.i("EXIST", "EXIST");
                }else{
                    Log.i("EXIST", "NOT");
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("ERROR", "File Not Found");
            }
```

selection[i] is the filename of the file that I need in the res/raw folder. The code always returns "NOT", which means it has not found the file that I want from the res/raw folder. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can access a resource through a `File` like that. Here's how I'm reading HTML files in my raw folder:

```
public static String getStringFromResource(Context context, @RawRes int id) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            stringBuilder.append(currentLine);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error opening raw resource: " + id);
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error closing raw resource: " + id, e);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The key part for you will be the `InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(id);` call which gets you a stream to the file. Use that stream to write to the output file you are exporting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to access the files in the raw folder as the files that needs to be merged are inside. The files that can be merged can be many and not limited to two. Is there a way to get the path to the raw folder so the File constructor can access it?

Comment: @xiotee The problem is that the raw folder is inside your apk. You could always load the files into memory (byte[]) and merge those. Or you could write the files to a local path and then merge. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage However depending on how you are merging you could just open the streams one at a time and write them to the same output file.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a byte array for your raw file:

```
 Resources res = context.getResources();
    InputStream inputStream = res.openRawResource(rawResource);
    try {
        byte[] b = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // exception thrown
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway that you can access the raw folder using a path that can be used by the File constructor to create a File object?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. I guess you could write it out from the raw folder to a File in the following way (but I haven't tested this out):

`File file = new File(path);
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(b);
            fos.close();`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out.